# MapBox mapview repeat padding in screen

Tags: android, mapbox

I use MapBox Android SDK 0.7.2 to get tiles from MapBox web service:

```
    WebSourceTileLayer webSourceTileLayer = new WebSourceTileLayer("MapBox", "http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/examples.map-zr0njcqy/-73.99,40.70,13/256x256.png?access_token=<my key>");

    webSourceTileLayer.setName("MapBox")
            .setAttribution("© MapBox © OpenStreetMap")
            .setMinimumZoomLevel(1)
            .setMaximumZoomLevel(18);
    mapView.setTileSource(webSourceTileLayer);

    mapView.setZoom(12);
    mapView.setCenter(mapView.getTileProvider().getCenterCoordinate());
```

so I get back a 256x256 png format tile. But the tile repeats in the screen while I suppose it should be one tile in the screen. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to just download the one tile from the Mapbox Web Service API?  If so using a regular Android HTTP client (ex: URLConnnection class) to download it and then paint it on the Canvas would serve this better.  TileLayers like WebSourceTileLayer are meant to download many different tiles and display them on the MapView as described.